# How do I control exports?

Tags: tropico-4

In the first scenario, I accepted an assignment from one of the factions to export some Tobacco.  Everything I find and click gives me an option to *import* stuff, but how do I *export*?  Is that managed automatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have a tobacco farm, when the tobacco is harvested and there's no cigar factory, it will automatically be hauled to the dock.

Comment: Keep in mind that it takes a while for crops to grow, so don't get concerned if your exports aren't starting to count up right away.

Comment: "A while" being two years for all crops except corn, which takes about one year.